# Can I run Javascript without a WebView, or can a WebView run without an Activity context, such as in a Service?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a HTML5 (JavaScript) backed app that I would like to port to Android.

In some cases, the JavaScript code needs to run in a background Service (no UI, so no WebView). For example, in order to sync.

From researching this, it doesn't appear that WebViews run without an Activity Context. Beyond that, it seems silly to use a UI View only to run code in the first place, but I'm not sure of the alternatives.

What is the best approach for accomplishing this?

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: What you're doing doesn't sound like you're porting an app.

Comment: @Falmarri, thanks for the really helpful comment ;)  Yes I am porting this app to Android.  However, there is a lot of well written and well tested backend code that has no real incentive to be rewritten in Java. This has nothing to do with the front end experience.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> From researching this, it doesn't appear that WebViews run without an Activity Context

Actually, they can. If you call `new WebView(ctxt)`, where `ctxt` is any sort of `Context`, it works. Leastways, it worked the last time I tried it, a couple of months ago.

> Beyond that, it seems silly to use a UI View only to run code in the first place, but I'm not sure of the alternatives.

Look for versions of Rhino, V8, spidermonkey, or other JavaScript engines that have been ported to Android. Rhino, in particular, is part of SL4A, and you can get a Rhino JAR from that project to embed in your application.

Comment: But a view that is not connected to a visible activity does only part of the functionality.

Comment: @Lev: Perhaps, though [the `WebView` approach works for others, though there are plenty of options](https://medium.com/tech-quizlet/comparison-shopping-searching-for-javascript-engines-for-android-bdc656538f2e#.slhsktu7m).