# Running JavaScript code on Android, without a visible browser

Tags: android

I have some Javascript code that modifies a webpage, coming from a browser plug-in. I want to reuse it in an Android app, that doesn't actually display  a browser view. That is, I want to have a service download an HTML document, inject the Javascript code, run it and parse the result. Here's my current solution:

1. In the service, create a View. Its layout is TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, and it's transparent.
2. In the View, create a WebView with visibility "gone".
3. In the WebView, load the HTML page and inject the Javascript.

The problem is that if I create the containing view with TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, I am at the mercy of the user giving me permission to "draw on top" and can't even explain to the user why I need it. But if I create the view with TYPE_APPLICATION, I need it to be in the context of an Activity, and the script won't work if the activity is stopped.

What is the best solution?

Comment: there is no other solution except 1) Using webview in Activity. 2) using TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT view in service.

Comment: How important is the HTML part of this, as opposed to evaluating Javascript on its own? There are ways and means of headlessly evaluating JS.

Comment: @RobPridham The JS works on the HTML document and assumes the standard DOM.

Comment: Turns out this has already been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438590/can-i-run-javascript-without-a-webview-or-can-a-webview-run-without-an-activity?rq=1 . In short, I only had to eliminate the View. How do I mark my own question as a duplicate?